# Macro to Highlight data if copy pasted on to excel sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I would like a macros code to detect if data is copy pasted on to excel sheet. I have a job in reviewing data and have found that some operators are copy pasting data instead of doing it in actuality. i would like someone to help with a vba code that could may be highlight data that has been copy pasted from an different excel sheet or workbook. If that is feasible..

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: If you mean, highlight the text *when* it is pasted, that is probably possible (although I don’t, offhand, know how) — but that would mean it would happen when the operators are doing it, so that’s probably not what you want.  If you mean *after the fact,* that’s probably impossible — once data is in the spreadsheet, it all looks the same (AFAIK). … … … … … … … … … … What you might be able to do is have a macro that triggers every time a user pastes and keeps a history (audit log) on a hidden sheet.

Comment: @Scott It's possible. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can see what the value is in the clipboard and compare it with what is in the Target when a sheet change is made.

First you need to add references to the clipboard.
Open Tools -> References and add as following:

[image]

Then double click the sheet you want to use this function on and paste the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim DataObj As MSForms.DataObject
    Set DataObj = New MSForms.DataObject
    DataObj.GetFromClipboard

    On Error GoTo ENDIT
    strPaste = DataObj.GetText(1) 'clip board value
    strPaste = Trim(Replace(Replace(strPaste, vbNewLine, " "), vbTab, " ")) ' make new lines and tabs space

    Values = ""
    If IsArray(Target.Value2) Then ' is there more than one line of values?
        For Each v In Target ' implode to string
            Values = Values & v & " "
        Next
        Values = Trim(Values) ' remove trailing space
    Else
        Values = Target.Value2
    End If

    If Values = strPaste Then ' are clipboard the same as range?
        Target.Interior.Color = vbRed
    End If
ENDIT:
End Sub
```

Example when used:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, the function is exactly that i wanted to check... Would it be possible to integrate this code in to a Macros enabled button in an excel sheet. The code must run and check the particular worksheet when clicked..... Thanks in advance

Comment: That won't be possible since we need to know what is in the clipboard. You could log each time someone pastes data to a specific workbook, either in the workbook visible, or in the workbook invisible (but still possible to be seen and edited) or completley incognito in a different file.

Comment: @Anuptv none of those solutions work for you? You can't know what the previous person has done in if you don't "record" it when it happens

Comment: would it be possible to record the daily entry and check ... with the marcos enabled button... I am a novice in the subject... Thank you for helping me out.... Would it be possible to send me your mail id... i could send you the format of the excel sheet that i use... its in a shared folder accessible for all

Comment: Or would there be a possibility to record as soon as the excel sheet is used , and the copied cells are highlighted.... but we dont change the color to make it obvious.... We change the fort a bit.. and then a macro could highlight the ones with the different font..  Sorry if i am asking a lot form you

Comment: If I would make a guess. A good way to use it is to tell the users to always have macros enabled, either force them or create a macro they will need and bundle them in the workbook. Then if we detect a copied values then write to a logfile the person who is using the computer, date and time, what value, what cell address, and as you say don't alarm the user about his error. This gives you a small txt file to read or import in Excel. Reason I want to use txt is because they are much much lighter than a xlsx. The lighter the log file is the less chance it is that someone notices.

Comment: Thank you @Andreas. would it be possible for you to guide me with step by step instructions please

Answer (score -1):

*This VBA(Macro) will allow you to Copy selected Range to another Sheet and highlight the selected Range to review.*

```
    Sub Copy&Paset()

     Dim xWs As Worksheet
     Dim Rng As Range

     Set Rng = Application.Selection
     Selection.Interior.Color = vbYellow
     Rng.Copy

     Set xWs = Sheets("Sheet2")
     xWs.Range("A1").PasteSpecial _        
     Paste:=xlPasteValues
     Application.CutCopyMode = False

    End Sub
```

**N.B.**

- Copy & Paste this Code as Standard Module with 
  the required Sheet (Source Sheet from where you 
  want to Copy Data).
- In this code `vbYellow`, `Sheet2` & 
  `Range("A1")` are editable.

Comment: Write your concern,, why this has been Down voted!!